# testing #define CONSTANT

Tags: c, constants, c-preprocessor

I'm not a programmer, but I need to do it! :) My problem is that I need to define some constants to set or not set some particular part of my code, and it is better to use #define than normal variables. The code is bellow. The isample can be equal to 0, 1, 2 or 3 according to a comparison between strings made before. Let's say that isample = 1, then the code print that the constant SAMPLE is equal 1, but then it enters in the if isample == 0!!! Something is wrong with the definition. What is happening? Is there another way to do it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> 

int main()
{

  int isample = 1; 

#define SAMPLE isample
  printf("\nSAMPLE %d", SAMPLE);

#if SAMPLE == 0 
#define A
#define AA
  printf("\nA");
#elif SAMPLE == 1 
#define B
  printf("\nB");
#elif SAMPLE == 2
#define C
  printf("\nC");
#else
  printf("\nOTHER");
#endif

  printf("\nBye");
}
```

RESULT:

```
SAMPLE 1
A
Bye
```

I also tried:

```
#define SAMPLE 4
#undef SAMPLE
#define SAMPLE isample
```

and the result is the same.

I also tried using variables. Instead of using the `#if` block, I used `if`:

```
  if (SAMPLE == 0)
    { 
#define A
#define AA
      printf("\nA");
    }
  else if (SAMPLE == 1)
   {
#define B
      printf("\nB");
   }
  else if (SAMPLE == 2)
   {
#define C
      printf("\nC");
   }
  else
   {
      printf("\nOTHER");
   }
  int abc, def;
#ifdef A
  abc = 1;
  def = 2;
#endif
#ifdef B
  abc = 3;
  def = 4;
#endif
#ifdef C
  abc = 5;
  def = 6;
#endif

  printf("\nabc %d, def %d\n", abc, def);
```

RESULT:

```
SAMPLE 1
B
abc 5, def 6
```

So all the `#define`'s were defined, not only the selected one, that it would be the `B`. `A, B and C` define part of the code that works in the same set of variables. I need to set one of them based on the `isample`.

Comment: Macros are processed when the program is compiled, not when it's run. They can't access ordinary variable values.

Comment: @JensGustedt `A` and `AA` are defined, `B` and `C` are not. Un-defined tokens are replaced with `0` for purposes of expression evaluation within `#if`

Comment: So to do what I want to do, I have 2 options:
1) Define "by hand" the `SAMPLE` each time that I run the code;
2) Use normal variables and take off all the `CONSTANT` that I defined.
I was doing the option 1, but I already had some problems with that, when I forgot to changed it, and as the code takes a long time to run, it is better to be sure that it will do the right thing. I think I will pick the option 2 and rewrite the code...

Answer (score 2):

You are approaching it using the wrong method. The value of `isample` is determined at run time, not compile time.

When you use

```
#define SAMPLE isample
```

everywhere the compiler sees `SAMPLE` as a token, it replaces that token by `isample`. That's not what you want. You want the compiler to replace all `SAMPLE` by the value of `isample`.

You need to set the value of `SAMPLE` using a compiler flag. With gcc, you can use:

```
gcc -DSAMPLE=1 ...
```

and remove the line

```
#define SAMPLE isample
```

Comment: You are right, but the isample will change in each time that I run the code. I didn't want to set it "by hand" (what I was doing till now). So maybe the best way is to not use #define and rewrite all those parts using variables. :/

Comment: @Thaise, if you want to change the branch of code to be executed based the value of `isample` at run time, you'll need to use `if-else` blocks, not the `#if SAMPLE == xxx` blocks.

Comment: But if I use `if-else` blocks as it is in the code above, all the `#define X` will be defined, not only the one selected by the `if`. The problem is that A, B and C define part of the code that works in the same set of variables. I need to set one of them based on the `isample`.

Comment: @Thaise, I don't see the problem as clearly as you do. Perhaps you can add more information to your post to explain what you see as the problem if you use `if-else` blocks.

Comment: I added above more explanation about it.